# SVG element has type HTMLUnknownElement when created inside jest test

Tags: javascript, svg, jestjs

I'm trying to create a svg element to use for a test that accepts it as a parameter, but it keeps failing because the svg element does not seem to be getting created properly. I am using jest 19.0.2.
Here is what I have:

```
describe('myFunc', () => {
  let div;
  let svg;

  beforeEach(() => {
    svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',"svg");
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', 'div-id');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    document.getElementById("div-id").appendChild(svg);
    console.log(svg);
  });

  test('some test', () => {
    myFunc(svg);
    // some expectation
  });
});
```

The console.log above outputs `HTMLUnknownElement {}`. The strange thing is this exact code actually does work if used outside a test. For example, if I look in the browser console when running the code on a local server I see the log statement successfully print the svg element (`<svg></svg>`). I cannot figure out why this does not work in my jest test.

Comment: I don't know jest at all, but from what I understand (and I could be wrong !) it uses jsdom, which doesn't support SVG DOM : https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1480#issuecomment-218326213

Comment: @Kaiido That is almost certainly the reason. I spent many hours suffering over this. Thank you for bringing that to my attention!

Comment: @Kaiido, make sure to write that as an answer so that kaitrono can mark it as the answer. Thank you for the help!